# While Searching Hide Parent Element if All Child Elements Are Hidden

Tags: javascript, search

I created a search box to search through all my links in my main container. It hides all the links that do not match the input from `#search-box`. The problem is that each `.item` has a `h2` tag, so when all the links in the element are hidden you are left with just the `h2` tags which look pretty tacky.

### HTML

```html
  <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search...">

 <div id="mainContainer" class="column-container row">
   <div class="item column">
     <h2>Forms</h2>
     <a href="/examples/forms/simple-contact-form.phtml">Simple contact form - WIP</a>
     <a href="/examples/forms/online-payment-form-networkmerchants.phtml">Online payment form using Network Merchants - WIP</a>
     <a href="/examples/forms/form-with-attachment.phtml">Form with attachment</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item column">
      <h2>Videos</h2>
        <a href="/examples/videos/responsive-youtube-video.phtml">Responsive Youtube Video</a>
     </div>
     <div class="item column">
       <h2>Calendars</h2>
       <a href="/examples/calendars/show-few-events.phtml">Show Few Events</a>
       <a href="/examples/calendars/show-all-events.phtml">Show All Events</a>
     </div>
   </div>
```

### JavaScript

```
searchBox = document.querySelector("#search-box");
contracts = document.querySelector(".examples");
var when = "keyup";

searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function (e)
{
  //declare variables
  var text = e.target.value;
  var options = contracts.querySelectorAll('.item>a');

  //loop through all examples to find a match
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
  {
    var option = options[i];
    var optionText = option.text;
    var lowerOptionText = optionText.toLowerCase();
    var lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
    var regex = new RegExp("^" + text, "i");
    var match = optionText.match(regex);
    var contains = lowerOptionText.indexOf(lowerText) != -1;

    //hide all content that doesn't match
    if(match || contains && text !== '')
    {
      option.style.display = 'block';
    }
    else
    {
      option.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
});
```

How can I modify the javascript code to hide the parent `.item` element if all the a links are hidden?

Comment: have you tried using .hide() and .show() for $(".item") ?

Comment: @jtylerm that is the goal, but first I need to figure out if all the links in the `.item` are hidden before hiding the `.item` container

Comment: are you trying to hide `.item`'s children elements from other software? if you're just tying to hide the elements from your users then hiding the parent should prevent them from interacting with any of the parent's child elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all your sections and find the link-elements inside each section. Then iterate over that links and check if the display-style is not `none`. If you found any link that is displayed, the section should be displayed, otherwise it should be hidden.

```js
let searchBox = document.querySelector("#search-box");
let contracts = document.querySelector("#mainContainer");
let when = "keyup";

searchBox.addEventListener("keyup", function (e) {
  let text = e.target.value;
  let options = contracts.querySelectorAll('.item > a');

  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    let option = options[i];
    let optionText = option.text;
    let lowerOptionText = optionText.toLowerCase();
    let lowerText = text.toLowerCase();
    let regex = new RegExp("^" + text, "i");
    let match = optionText.match(regex);
    let contains = lowerOptionText.indexOf(lowerText) != -1;

    if(match || contains && text !== '') {
      option.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      option.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  
  // Hide sections when all links are hidden
  let sections = contracts.querySelectorAll('.item');
  for (let j = 0; j < sections.length; j++) {
    let anyLinkNotHidden = false;
    let links = sections[j].querySelectorAll('a');
    for (let k = 0; k < links.length; k++) {
      if (links[k].style.display != 'none') {
        anyLinkNotHidden = true;
      }
    }
    if (anyLinkNotHidden) {
      sections[j].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      sections[j].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
  
});
```

```html
  <input type="search" id="search-box" placeholder="Search...">

 <div id="mainContainer" class="column-container row">
   <div class="item column">
     <h2>Forms</h2>
     <a href="/examples/forms/simple-contact-form.phtml">Simple contact form - WIP</a>
     <a href="/examples/forms/online-payment-form-networkmerchants.phtml">Online payment form using Network Merchants - WIP</a>
     <a href="/examples/forms/form-with-attachment.phtml">Form with attachment</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item column">
      <h2>Videos</h2>
        <a href="/examples/videos/responsive-youtube-video.phtml">Responsive Youtube Video</a>
     </div>
     <div class="item column">
       <h2>Calendars</h2>
       <a href="/examples/calendars/show-few-events.phtml">Show Few Events</a>
       <a href="/examples/calendars/show-all-events.phtml">Show All Events</a>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!!